# How do I check the first items of a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array like this:

```
schedule
=> [["wednesday", 3, 29], ["wednesday", 4, 30], ["wednesday", 4, 33]]
```

And I just want to see if the first two values are in the array:

```
schedule.include?(['wednesday', 3])
=> false
```

I know why the value is false but I can't think of a way to search this array and disregard the last value.

Comment: When you say disregard the last value, do you mean the 29?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good solution

```
> previous_schedule.any?{|x| x[0] == "wednesday" and x[1] == 3}
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby Arrays actually have a method `first`:

```
schedule = [["wednesday", 3, 29], ["wednesday", 4, 30], ["wednesday", 4, 33]] 
schedule.any?{|item| item.first(2) == ['wednesday', 3]} #=> true
```